# Upgrading Tailwind CSS to v3, using Storybook and React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, storybook

I am working on Storybook with React and Typescript. I am using Tailwind CSS by installing the following packages as per the documentation:

```js
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.17",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
```

And I've added the postcss configuration as following:

```js
    module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
       },
    };
```

And everything works as expected. The point is, I'm using Tailwind CSS version 2 which is a bit old. How can I update to the latest version while keeping everything working properly?

Thanks in advance.